# How to calculate an address of a label in MIPS ASSEMBLY?

Tags: assembly, mips

How to calculate the address of the label where?

[image]

Comment: Surely you can figure out what the effective address will be on the last line by just doing the operations with pen and paper?

Comment: I did separate 0x3c011001 to it's I format and figure out that the address of where label is 0x00001001. Is this correct?

Comment: No. As you can see, that `lw $t2,where($t1)` from your source code was translated into 3 actual MIPS instructions (listed in the "Basic" column). You need to do all of those operations.

Comment: Is where's label address 0x1001003d?

Comment: why don't you single step up to the `lw` instruction on 40006c, and when you are there the effective address will be `$1 + 0x3d`.  However, that is not necessarily where `where` is b/c usually we would simply use `lw $t2, where` not `lw $t2, where($t1)`

Comment: Wow, MARS is so dumb at assembling pseudo-instructions like `lw` with a large address.  IDK why it uses an `addu` between the address high-half and the register, instead of using `lui` for the high half and the `lw` 16-bit signed displacement for the low half, using the same register as the source.